# How to set the reactjs TransitionGroup classes in jss?

Tags: reactjs, jss

I'm using [jss](http://cssinjs.org/react-jss?v=v8.3.5) and [TransitionGroup](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/). How can I set the step-enter-active class in jss?

css

```
.step-enter {
 opacity: 0;
}
.step-enter.step-enter-active {
 opacity: 1;
 transition-duration: 100ms;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.665, 0.320, 1), linear;
}
```

current jss

```
const styles = {
  step: {
    background: props => props.color
  },
}

const Button = ({classes}) => (
  <button className={classes.step}>test</button>
)
```

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the source file [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/CSSTransition.js).

According to that, you can either have a string value for the `classNames` prop or an object of the following shape:

```
classNames={{
  appear: 'my-appear',
  appearActive: 'my-active-appear',
  enter: 'my-enter',
  enterActive: 'my-active-enter',
  enterDone: 'my-done-enter,
  exit: 'my-exit',
  exitActive: 'my-active-exit',
  exitDone: 'my-done-exit,
}}
```

Which means you can pass all your JSS generated class names into it.

```
const Button = ({classes}) => (
  <button className={{ appear: classes.step, enter: classes.enter, /* and so on...*/ }}>test</button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With TransitionGroup, you don't need to explicitly add the -enter and -enter-active classes to the component. This is managed automatically by the CSSTransition component.

The CSSTransition component will use the class name to apply to the enter classes. In your case if you use:

```
<CSSTransition className="step">
```

`step-enter` and `step-enter-active` will be applied by the component.

So your button component could be something like:

```
const Button = ({classes}) => (
  <CSSTransition className="step" in={true}>
    <button className={classes.step}>test</button>
  </CSSTransition>
)
```

You'll need to import the css file containing the step-enter and step-enter-active classes.

The react-transition-group docs have pretty good examples around this (https://codesandbox.io/s/yv645oq21x?from-embed)

To declare the step-enter classes using JSS you could use the jss-global plugin. This allows you to declare global css classes, with predetermined class names.

It would like something like:

```
const styles = {
  '@global': {
    '.step-enter': {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  },
  step: {
    background: props => props.color
  },
}
```

More details on jss-global can be found at: http://cssinjs.org/jss-global

Comment: I wanted to declare the step-enter values inside the react-file.js because the project does not use traditional css